# JQuery html() Not Working with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that uses JQuery to change the html of a div. I have two functions that call each other by the function setTimeout for 2 second delay. When the page loads the original html is of the div is saved into a variable. Then the first function is called that changes the div's html. So far the code works as expected. Then the second function is called that sets the div's html to the original html, but the div's html does not change on the page, but if I console.log the html it prints the original html. I'm not sure why the page will not undate with the origial html. Here is my code.

[html code](https://jsfiddle.net/n3qj5q8c/1/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    ORIG_LIST_HTML = $('#List').html();
    setTimeout(changeOne,2000);
});
function changeOne(){
    $('#List').html('<h1>new text</h1>');
    setTimeout(changeTwo,2000);
}
function changeTwo(){
    $('#Scroll-Table').html(ORIG_LIST_HTML);
    setTimeout(changeOne,2000);
    console.log($('#List').html());
    console.log(ORIG_LIST_HTML);
}
```

My question is how do I get my page to update my div's html?

******EDIT******

Here is my full code:

https://jsfiddle.net/n3qj5q8c/4/

I am using bootstrap so the css wont be right, but it shows the problem.

Comment: `$('#List').html(ORIG_LIST_HTML);`

Comment: Should both functions operate on the same DIV, because they aren't...

Comment: There is no element with id Scroll-Table.

Comment: no `$('#Scroll-Table')` in  demo

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n3qj5q8c/2/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please check my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$('#Scroll-Table').html(ORIG_LIST_HTML);
```

to this:

```
$('#List').html(ORIG_LIST_HTML);
```

There is no element with an id of #Scroll-Table.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please check my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your complete code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="List" class="row">
    <ul id="scroller" class="col-xs-12">
        <li>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2">Paul Jones</div>
                <div class="col-xs-1">Test</div>
                <div class="col-xs-1">Test</div>
                <div class="col-xs-1">Test</div>
                <div class="col-xs-1">YES</div>
                <div class="col-xs-1">YES</div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        ORIG_LIST_HTML = $('#List').html();
        setTimeout(changeOne,2000);
    });
    function changeOne(){
    $('#List').html('<h1>new text</h1>');
        setTimeout(changeTwo,2000);
        console.log('In Chnage One');
        console.log($('#List').html());
    }
    function changeTwo(){
    $('#List').html(ORIG_LIST_HTML);
        setTimeout(changeOne,2000);
        console.log('In Chnage Two');
        console.log($('#List').html());
        console.log(ORIG_LIST_HTML);
    }
</script>
```

what you are doing is you are setting up your html to different div.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please check my updated code.

Comment: Sorry to ask you again,.  you have said : My question is how do I get my page to update my div's html?   what do you mean by it. ? you want any page to update the values ?

Comment: I'm for [link](https://jsfiddle.net/n3qj5q8c/4/) I am wanting to know how to get the JQuery html function to update the div with the id 'Scroll-Table'